# How to read Windows 7 BSOD Blue Screen of Death on Startup

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod

After replacing the CMOS battery, the Dell Optiplex 990 starts up with the Windows logo, then shows BSOD on start-up. Too fast to read, re-boots immediately into Windows recovery. Windows recovery cannot fix the problem. Safe mode is not possible even with `bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal`. No minidump file is created.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl\AutoReboot` is 0 which surprises me so why is the BSOD not readable?

The Dell diagnostics accessible from the BIOS pass ok. I reset BIOS settings to default to be safe.

Please help me getting the error messages as shown on the BSOD, or anything in the direction of analyzing the problem. The command `bcdedit /set {default} bootlog Yes` executes successfully but ntbtlog.txt is missing. This indicates that the driver needed for logging cannot be loaded. Many thanks.

Comment: If you can boot into the Command Prompt from the recovery, use the following command for the next boot to go directly to safe mode: `bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal`. Not to frighten you, but you shouldn't exclude a destructive virus or a hardware problem. You might need to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Thanks. Making progress :) After re-boot, many lines display the installation of drivers, and then the BSOD flashes, then re-boots immediately into Windows recovery. So it crashed before safe mode. I have an up to date virus checker but the clock chip has trouble that is why I changed the battery.
Good news is that something has changed, the display of the driver installation. How do I get the information out about the crash? How can I log the startup and BSOD or halt this so I can see it?

Comment: from recovery you can goto startup settings and then tell it to disable automatic restart on system failure. This should leave the BSOD on the screen until you cycle power.

Comment: @Larryc thanks. how to get to that option from [here](http://cdn.windowstechies.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/CpWz_522.png)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty typically a problem after resetting your BIOS.

First, continue to tap F8 after powering on your system to enable the advanced startup menu. Choose “Disable automatic restart on system failure.”

At this point, you will likely see a STOP 0x0000007B - INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE.

This simply means you changed the mode of your SATA controller from AHCI/RAID to IDE or vice-versa. This happens because you had it set to a non-default setting, and changing the battery reset it to default.

Go in to your BIOS and toggle it from one mode to the other, save the settings and try booting again.

Do not start running commands or startup repair to try to fix the problem. It can’t fix it, and it will only make it impossible to boot after switching to the correct BIOS settings.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x7b--inaccessible-boot-device

Comment: Be sure to set the correct date and time in the bios after replacing the battery